# How do I configure IdP metadata with HTTP url that can fallback to local file?

Tags: spring-saml

Spring Security SAML documentation suggests that you can configure the metadata for an Identity Provider by providing its metadata url, and having it fallback to a downloaded copy on your local filesystem (in case of a network hiccup).

I want to use `FileBackedHTTPMetadataProvider` which appears to be a hybrid of `HTTPMetadataProvider` and `FilesystemMetadataProvider`, however there's no documentation for how to use it in your `securityContext.xml`

It has two constructors:

- @DEPRECATED String metadataURL, int requestTimeout, String backupFilePath
- Timer backgroundTaskTimer, HttpClient client, String metadataURL, String backupFilePath

The url, timeout, file looks easier to construct, I don't have a timer, or httpclient...

Here is my thought on how I would want to do this, but I don't know how to get my metadata file from the classpath... Maybe thats a different question.

```
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FileBackedHTTPMetadataProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="https://adfs.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
    <constructor-arg><value type="int">15000</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
            <constructor-arg value="/metadata/Federation_idp.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

That ClasspathResource bit doesn't compile/run. It wants a string.

```
<contructor-arg value="/home/user/adfsmetadata/Federation_idp.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the constructor just needs a String, you just gotta make your arg of the right type.  Like so:

```
<constructor-arg>
    <value type="java.lang.String">/dir/dir/metadata/Federation_idp.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
```

If the server doesn't blow up, but it's not picking up your file, you can see if Java is really grabbing path you think try FileMon (windows) or an alternative like fs_usage (OS X) with some grepping. :)